# How to call 3rd Party OAuth 2.0 API from NetSuite suitelet?

Tags: http, https, oauth-2.0, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I need to make oAuth 2.0 3rd party API call from NetSuite. How to request third party oauth2 token (External API) from NetSuite Script?